Regarding Configdb set and get issues in UVM
My question is when i am doing set in my_test class and get in componentA class, however get is causing issue since i am trying to assign compA instance names i.e compA[0] compA[1] to be assigned to inline constrains respectively in componenetA class, any suggestion will be help full thank you.
I am providing the EDA play ground link 
I have used debug messages and info's and checked the paths they seem right but get is not able to retrieve them, i am shared the link of my effort thank you.I am providing the EDA play ground link 
package my_uvm_pkg;
  `include "uvm_macros.svh"
  import uvm_pkg::*;

  // Define your shared enumeration here
  typedef enum bit[2:1] {COMPA, COMPAA} diff_packet;

endpackage

include "my_uvm_pkg.sv" include "packet.sv"
include "componentA.sv" include "componentAA.sv"
include "componentB.sv" include "coverage.sv"
`include "my_test.sv"
module top();
  import my_uvm_pkg::*;  
  initial begin 
    run_test();
    
    #1000;
    $finish;
  end
endmodule


import my_uvm_pkg::*;
class packet extends uvm_object;
  
  rand bit [7:0] addr;
  rand bit [7:0] data;
  rand diff_packet dif_pkt;
  
  `uvm_object_utils_begin(packet)
    `uvm_field_int(addr, UVM_ALL_ON)
    `uvm_field_int(data, UVM_ALL_ON)
    `uvm_field_enum(diff_packet, dif_pkt, UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_object_utils_end
  
  
  function new(string name = "packet");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction
  
  constraint dis_pkt {
    dif_pkt dist {COMPA := 2, COMPAA := 1}; 
    
    unique {addr};
    addr inside {[1:254]};    
  }   
endclass


import my_uvm_pkg::*;  
class componentA extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(componentA)
  
  uvm_blocking_put_port #(packet) m_put_portA;
  
  uvm_analysis_port#(packet) ap_port;
  
  int m_num_tx;
  static int pkt_countA;
  
  diff_packet my_dif_pkt_type; 
  
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction
  
  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    m_put_portA = new("m_put_portA",this);  
    ap_port     = new("ap_port",this);
    
    // Inside build_phase of componentA and componentAA
    if (!uvm_config_db#(int)::get(this, "", "m_num_tx", m_num_tx)) begin
     `uvm_warning("CFG", "m_num_tx not set; using default")
    end
    
    `uvm_info("CFG_GET", $sformatf("Attempting to retrieve dif_pkt_type for %s", get_full_name()), UVM_LOW);

    
    //if (!uvm_config_db#(diff_packet)::get(this, "", "dif_pkt_type", my_dif_pkt_type)) begin
    if (!uvm_config_db#(diff_packet)::get(this, get_full_name(), "dif_pkt_type", my_dif_pkt_type)) begin

      `uvm_warning("CFG", $sformatf("dif_pkt_type not set; defaulting to COMPA for %s", get_full_name()));
      my_dif_pkt_type = COMPA; // Default to COMPA if not set
    end
    
  endfunction
  
  virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this);
    repeat(m_num_tx) begin
      packet pkt = packet::type_id::create("pkt");     
       pkt_countA++;
      pkt.dif_pkt = COMPA;
      assert(pkt.randomize());// with {dif_pkt == my_dif_pkt_type;});     
      `uvm_info("COMPA: my_dif_pkt_type ", $sformatf("[CompA PACKET]   pkt_countA=%0d dif_pkt_type=%s Packet sent to CompB ",  pkt_countA, pkt.dif_pkt.name()  ), UVM_LOW)
      pkt.print(uvm_default_line_printer);           
      m_put_portA.put(pkt);        
      ap_port.write(pkt);               
    end 
    phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask
  
endclass

class componentB extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(componentB)
  
  uvm_blocking_put_imp #(packet, componentB) m_put_impB;
  uvm_blocking_put_imp #(packet, componentB) m_put_impBB;
  int m_num_tx;
  rand bit [7:0] arrayA[bit[7:0]];
  rand bit [7:0] arrayAA[bit[7:0]]; 
  
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction
  
  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    m_put_impB = new("m_put_impB",this);  
    m_put_impBB = new("m_put_impBB",this);  
  endfunction    
  
 virtual task put (packet pkt);     
  if(pkt.dif_pkt == COMPA) begin  
    arrayA[pkt.addr] = pkt.data;
    `uvm_info("COMPA", $sformatf("[ENUM[%s]] Packet received from CompA  arrayA[%0h] = %0h ", pkt.dif_pkt.name, pkt.addr, pkt.data  ), UVM_LOW) 
    if (pkt.data == arrayA[pkt.addr]) begin
      `uvm_info("COMPA", $sformatf("[PASS][ENUM[%s]] pkt.data=%0h arrayA[%0h]=%0h", pkt.dif_pkt.name, pkt.data, pkt.addr, arrayA[pkt.addr] ), UVM_LOW)
    end else begin
      `uvm_info("COMPA", $sformatf("[FAIL][ENUM[%s]] pkt.data=%0h arrayA[%0h]=%0h", pkt.dif_pkt.name, pkt.data, pkt.addr, arrayA[pkt.addr] ), UVM_LOW)
    end
    
  end else if(pkt.dif_pkt == COMPAA) begin
    arrayAA[pkt.addr] = pkt.data;
    `uvm_info("COMPAA", $sformatf("[ENUM[%s]] Packet received from CompAA  arrayAA[%0h] = %0h ", pkt.dif_pkt.name, pkt.addr, pkt.data  ), UVM_LOW)
    if (pkt.data == arrayAA[pkt.addr]) begin
      `uvm_info("COMPAA", $sformatf("[PASS][ENUM[%s]] pkt.data=%0h arrayAA[%0h]=%0h", pkt.dif_pkt.name, pkt.data, pkt.addr, arrayAA[pkt.addr] ), UVM_LOW)
    end else begin
      `uvm_info("COMPAA", $sformatf("[FAIL][ENUM[%s]] pkt.data=%0h arrayAA[%0h]=%0h", pkt.dif_pkt.name, pkt.data, pkt.addr, arrayAA[pkt.addr] ), UVM_LOW)
    end
  end 
     
 endtask  
endclass


import my_uvm_pkg::*;  

class my_test extends uvm_test;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_test)
  
  localparam int num_of_comp = 2;
  
  componentA compA[num_of_comp];
  componentAA compAA;
  componentB compB;
  coverage cov;
  
  int loop_num = 1;
  
  
  function new(string name = "my_test", uvm_component parent = null);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction
  
  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    
    foreach(compA[i])begin
       string inst_name;
       diff_packet type_for_this_instance;
       $sformat(inst_name, "compA[%0d]", i);
       compA[i] = componentA::type_id::create(inst_name, this);
      
      `uvm_info("CFG_SET", $sformatf("Setting dif_pkt_type for %s to %s to %s", inst_name, type_for_this_instance.name(), get_full_name() ), UVM_LOW);


     // Assume you want to alternate the packet type between COMPA and COMPAA for each instance
     type_for_this_instance = (i % 2 == 0) ? COMPA : COMPAA;
    uvm_config_db#(diff_packet)::set(this, $sformatf("%s.dif_pkt_type", inst_name), "dif_pkt_type", type_for_this_instance);
 

    end
    
    compAA = componentAA::type_id::create("compAA", this);
    compB = componentB::type_id::create("compB", this);
    
    //compA.m_num_tx = 2;
    //compAA.m_num_tx = 2;
    // In my_test::build_phase or somewhere appropriate
    //uvm_config_db#(int)::set(this, "compA", "m_num_tx", loop_num);
    foreach(compA[i]) begin
     string inst_name;
     $sformat(inst_name, "compA[%0d]", i);
     uvm_config_db#(int)::set(this, inst_name, "m_num_tx", loop_num);
    end

    uvm_config_db#(int)::set(this, "compAA", "m_num_tx", loop_num);
    
    cov   = coverage::type_id::create("cov", this);
    
    

  endfunction
  
  
  virtual function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    foreach(compA[i]) begin
      compA[i].m_put_portA.connect(compB.m_put_impB);
    end
    
    compAA.m_put_portAA.connect(compB.m_put_impBB);   
    
   foreach(compA[i]) begin 
     if (compA[i].ap_port != null && cov.analysis_export != null)
        compA[i].ap_port.connect(cov.analysis_export);
     else 
       `uvm_error("NULL_OBJ", "One of the objects is null in connect_phase")
       
   end//foreach

  endfunction
  
  
  virtual function void extract_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.extract_phase(phase);
    cov.report_coverage();
  endfunction
  
  constraint array_size_c{  
    compB.arrayA.size() == 2;
    compB.arrayAA.size() == 2;
    
    //compA.m_num_tx inside {[1:4]};
    //compAA.m_num_tx == compA.m_num_tx;
  }
  
endclass


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have provided code link already in my question its in EDA play ground.

in componentA class where i am doing   assert(pkt.randomize());// with {dif_pkt == my_dif_pkt_type;});  i want the instance name to come in in this inline constraint as and when localparam int num_of_comp = 2; increases in my_test class

inst_name for your uvm_config_db::set call is wrong.
You need to modify this as below
uvm_config_db#(diff_packet)::set(this, $sformatf("uvm_test_top.%s", inst_name), "dif_pkt_type", type_for_this_instance);

uvm_test_top.<instance_name> is the actual instance name.

in my my_uvm_pkg i have  typedef enum bit[2:1] {COMPA, COMPAA} diff_packet;
but when in my  my_test class  when i cange localparam int num_of_comp = 2; which means 2 components will be created compA[0] compA[1] so but enum members are still only 2 how can i make it generic so the enum in package get updated to number of components are created ?
